# chef attributes not overridden on computed attributed

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, chef-solo

Today i upgraded opscode jenkins cookbook of my chef solo installation. Except for a couple of changes from version 0.8 which worked fine for me (like removing jenkins_data attribute) i noticed that the definition of some of attributes has also been [changed](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins/commit/9a3c5c9c83b191b0f52297db2aae48d7be55488f#commitcomment-4059279): 
from

```
default['jenkins']['server']['url']  = "http://#{node['jenkins']['server']['host']}:#{node['jenkins']['server']['port']}"
```

to

```
default['jenkins']['server']['url']  = "http://#{default['jenkins']['server']['host']}:#{default['jenkins']['server']['port']}"
```

So in a new version jenkins.server.url is defined as concatenation of **DEFAULT** *jenkins.server.host* : and **DEFAULT** *jenkins.server.port*. The problem is that when my role defines default/override attribute  *jenkins.server.port* a new value is correctly reflected in attribute but *jenkins.server.url* still references an original port.
It seems like cookbooks attributes are evaluated first and then can be overridden by roles attributes. According to [article](http://docs.opscode.com/breaking_changes_chef_11.html#computing-attributes-from-attributes) it was about to work like that in chef 10 but shall be fixed in chef 11. I am pretty sure i am using chef 11 - when my vagrant-chef runs i can see:

```
 INFO: *** Chef 11.4.2 ***
```

Any help on this?

Answer (score 0):

The recipe is working as intended (though arguably shouldn't be using `default` instead of `node`), so you'd have to change all attributes that use defaults in them.